# TypeError: jwt(...).unless is not a function when mocking with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock the `.unless` function of `express-jwt` and currently have this mock setup to compare a JWT with an admin and non admin. This worked perfect until we added `.unless` and I am not sure the best way to approach the issue.

```
jest.mock("express-jwt", () => {
  return options => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      receivedToken = req.headers.authorization.substring(7);
      req.user = { preferred_username: "tester" };
      next();
    };
  };
});
```

That is the mock. I have tried moving that into a const and adding: `mockFun.unless = jest.fn()` but to no avail.

Thanks

Edit:

One of the things I tried is below:

```
jest.mock("express-jwt", () => {
  const mockFunc = () => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      receivedToken = req.headers.authorization.substring(7);
      req.user = { preferred_username: "tester" };
      next();
    };
  };

  mockFunc.unless = jest.fn();

  return mockFunc
});
```

Comment: *I have tried moving that into a const* - what exactly did you do?

Comment: @EstusFlask Made an edit to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unless` is supposed to be a method on a function that `jwt()` returns while currently it's a method on `jwt` itself.

Should be:

```
jest.mock("express-jwt", () => {
  const mockFunc = jest.fn((req, res, next) => {
   ...
  });

  mockFunc.unless = jest.fn((req, res, next) => {
   ...
  });

  return jest.fn(() => mockFunc);
});
```